# UIImageView image not showing up at all

Tags: iphone, objective-c

im using the followng method , to display image when a timestamp detecetd , am using 
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),   to do UIImageView , its never works its should open a new screen full size image that it  ,

```
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{



            UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.jpg"];

            UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];

            [myImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 200)];

            [myImageView release];
       ;
       });
```

my full code

```
 - (void) onPayload:(PayloadEvent *) event

{

NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSString *header = @"[OnPayload] ";

if (event.payloadType == TYPE_IDENTIFIED)

{


    if ((event.contentID != -1) && (event.timeStamp == -1))

    {

        [mUI performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(Trace:) withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ StaticID detected: %x\t\tConfidence: %f\n", header,(int)event.contentID, event.confidence]  waitUntilDone:NO];

    }

    if ((event.timeStamp != -1) && (event.contentID == -1))



    {

        [mUI performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(Trace:) withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Timestamp detected: %f\t\tConfidence: %f\n", header, event.timeStamp, event.confidence]  waitUntilDone:NO];
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),  ^{

            UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.jpg"];

            UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];

            [myImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 200)];

            [myImageView release];



;  });
```

Comment: By the way: this has nothing to do with Xcode at all.

Comment: @Marco DonJuan - what type of object did you subclass here? is it a uiviewcontroller? or just a uiview? or something else entirely?

Comment: [self.view addSubview:myImageView];

Comment: @MarcoDonJuan - i dont think you understand me. The class you a re operating in, what is its parent class? In your header file, theres something like '@interface MyClass : Parentclass' of what type is parentclass?

Answer (score 1):

You never add `myImageView` to any view as a subview.

Comment: im getting Property 'View; not found on object of type error after i added  it

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this one in your code.

```
[self.view addSubview:myImageView];
```

Comment: im getting Property 'View; not found on object of type   error after i added sel.view

Comment: try to write [self.view addSubview:myImageView]; instead of sel.view

Comment: sir, its typo mistake here but in the code its self.view . and sorry for wasting your precious time.!

Comment: What problem your are getting.

Comment: here is  error msg from xcode " Property 'View; not found on object of type ..."

Comment: property view not found on object of type this on google and find your solution

Comment: what type of object is 'self' referencing here ? is it a uiviewcontroller? or just a uiview? or something else entirely?

Comment: [self.view addSubview:myImageView];

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an ImageView, assigning an Image to it and releasing the ImageView. In other words, you're not displaying the ImageView anywhere.

If you can't do something like `[self.view addSubview:imageView]`, it means that you're not running this code on a `UIViewController` subclass.

You basically need to add this ImageView you're creating as a subview for the current view before releasing it.

In which class are you running this code? Do you know which View Controller is currently being displayed?